# PHP first 3 then break and continue again?

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I'm trying to sort everything out using array & loops
lets say this is an array,

```
$arr = array('One','Two','Three','Four','Five','Six');
```

i want to select first three of them to be used as
$arr[0], $arr[1] and $arr[2]
this ends up with one,two,three
i want to use the same for next 3.. 
something to break it and use the same 0 1 2 index again to return second three
here's an example to explain more,

```
$arr = array('One','Two','Three','Four','Five','Six');

  echo $arr[0].$arr[1].$arr[2]; // OneTwoThree
        break; // < ??
  echo $arr[0].$arr[1].$arr[2]; // FourFiveSix
```

also, i want to use it with foreach loop

```
$arr = array('One','Two','Three','Four','Five','Six');
  foreach($arr as $num){
  echo $num; // OneTwoThree
   if($something == 3){ // < ??
        break; // < ??
    }
  echo $num;   // FourFiveSix
   }
```

and what im trying to do is using each three arrays of the array to use them later

Comment: Use [`array_chunk($arr, 3);`](http://us.php.net/array_chunk)

Comment: What are you *actually* trying to do? You might be overthinking the problem.

Comment: I think he wants line breaks... and is completely misunderstanding the usage of "break"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [array_chunk](http://php.net/array_chunk) and loop over the result:

```
foreach(array_chunk($arr, 3) as $a) {
  echo $a[0], $a[1], $a[2];
}
```

Here it is with added linebreaks:

```
foreach(array_chunk($arr, 3) as $a) {
  echo $a[0], $a[1], $a[2], "<br>\n";
}
```

**Note:** The last element may have less than three elements! A possible fix for this is to use [implode](http://php.net/implode) to concatenate the elements:

```
foreach(array_chunk($arr, 3) as $a) {
  echo implode('', $a), "<br>\n";
}
```

Comment: RoseWarad, array_chunk will split $arr into tuples of three. Each time the foreach loop runs $a will have (up to) three different elements from $arr. Try it!

Answer (score 1):

Edit: `array_chunk()` is a lot more sensible...early mornings

```
<?php
$arr = array('One','Two','Three','Four','Five','Six');


for($i = 0, $i < count($arr); ++$i)
{
    if( ! ($i + 1) % 3)
    {
        continue;
    }

    echo $arr[$i - 2] . $arr[$i - 1] . $arr[$i]
}
```

Comment: Why not just increment by three instead of the if statement?

Comment: Good question, I didn't think of that, I had only just woken up! Thanks for the pointer